# Prolog Dynamic Predicates Basic Usage

Tags: prolog, prolog-assert

with this knowledge base using https://swish.swi-prolog.org

```
:- dynamic happy/1.

go:-
    assert(happy(mia)),
    write(happy(mia)).
```

if I run `go.` I get

```
happy(mia)
true
```

If I just have

```
:- dynamic happy/1.

assert(happy(mia)).
```

and run `happy(mia)`, I get `false`.

What fundamental concept am I missing please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write:

```
assert(happy(mia)).
```

you are (re)**defining** the predicate `assert/1`, not **calling** it as in your definition of the `go/0` predicate. Thus, `happy(mia)` is **never** added to the database. The query fails as the predicate `happy/1` is know by the system (thanks to the `dynamic/1` directive) but have no clauses.

Most Prolog systems prevent the redefinition of standard built-in predicates. But `assert/1` is a legacy/deprecated predicate. That explains why SWI-Prolog doesn't complain about the redefinition. Always use the standard `assertz/1` predicate instead of `assert/1`.